# Mi id_producto por ende producto me llega NULL siempre en POSTMAN. Spring - JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, json, spring, postman

Estoy haciendo un trabajo practico con un sistema de facturacion. Lo que me está pasando es que cuando hago un POST de mi factura, mi tabla Linea se autocompleta toda menos la id_producto por ende el producto es  null (me di cuenta cuando debugie) ademas no me permite poder controlar el stock con la cantidad solicitada en la linea. No se en que estoy fallando, le he consultado a chatGPT pero no consigue darme una respuesta precisa si no que empieza un loop interminable de las mismas cosas. Dejo mis entidades, mi controlador y servicio de Factura y ademas el metodo POST que estoy utilizando. Muchas gracias espero su ayuda!

Clase cliente:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter

public class Cliente {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id_cliente;
    @Column
    private String nombre;
    @Column
    private String apellido;
    @Column
    @JsonProperty("dni")
    private String dni;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cliente", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Factura> facturas = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Clase producto:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Producto {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_producto")
    private Integer id_producto;
    @Column
    private String nombre;
    @Column
    private double precio;
    @Column
    private int stock;

}
```

Clase linea:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Linea {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer lineaId;
    private String descripcion;
    private Integer cantidad;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_factura")
    private Factura factura;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_producto")
    private Producto producto;


    public double getPrecio() {
        if (producto != null && cantidad != null) {
            return producto.getPrecio() * cantidad;
        }
        return 0.0;
    }

}
```

Clase factura:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Factura {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_factura")
    private Integer id_factura;
    @Column
    private LocalDate fecha;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="factura", fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Linea> lineas;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_cliente")
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private Cliente cliente;


    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        this.fecha = LocalDate.now();
    }

    public void addLinea(Linea linea){
        this.lineas.add(linea);
        linea.setFactura(this);
    }

   
}
```

Mi body del POST:

```
{
  "lineas": [
    {
      "producto": {
        "id_producto": 1
      },
      "cantidad": 3,
      "descripcion": "asdasd"
      
    },
    {
      "producto": {
        "id_producto": 2
      },
      "cantidad": 3,
      "descripcion": "asdasd"
    }
  ],
  "cliente": {
    "id_cliente": 1
  }
}
```

Metodo POST del SERVICIO:

```java
  public ResponseEntity<?> guardarFactura(Factura factura) {
        Map<String,Object> mensaje = new HashMap<>();

        try {
            Cliente cliente = factura.getCliente();
            if (cliente != null) {
                factura.setCliente(cliente);
            }
            for (Linea linea : factura.getLineas()) {
                Producto producto = linea.getProducto();
                if (producto != null) {
                    Optional<Producto> optionalProducto = repositorioProducto.findById(producto.getId_producto());
                    if (optionalProducto.isPresent()) {
                        linea.setProducto(optionalProducto.get());
                    }
                }
                linea.setFactura(factura);
            }
            repositorioFactura.save(factura);

            mensaje.put("success",Boolean.TRUE);
            mensaje.put("mensaje",String.format("Factura correctamente agregada"));
            return ResponseEntity.ok(mensaje);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mensaje.put("succes",Boolean.FALSE);
            mensaje.put("mensaje",String.format("No se pudo guardar la factura"));
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(mensaje);
        }
    }
```

Controlador metodo POST:

```
// POST -
    @PostMapping("/alta")
    public ResponseEntity<?> postFactura(@RequestBody Factura Factura) {
        return servicioFactura.guardarFactura(Factura);
    }
```

```
Mi tabla Linea en SQL queda con todo insertado menos la id_producto.
```

Answer (score 0):

La id se crea cuando creas la clase con el constructo vacio.
entonces si suponemos que que el id de clinte 1 existe deberia tener y findbyid para sacar el cliente de la BD y setearlo
caso de que el id no exista lo creamos cliente c = new cliente(); y seteamos los datos menos el id que se genera automaticamete.
caso de que tu quieras manejar el id debes quitar     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
y usar el set ID

Comment: Hola buen dia entiendo a lo que vas. Pero mi problema esta con el Producto, cuando paso por POST mi JSON del producto, el producto esta null (y existe en la BD) pero el problema es que no se me setea en mi tabla linea, si los demas atributos, hasta la id factura misma que se crea en el POST. Por ende con el PRODUCTO en null no puedo manejar la validacion entre stock y cantidad.

Comment: haz un findbyid del rpdocuto y si existe y lo encuentra lo seteas es lo mas sencillo

Comment: El probelema es no me lo encuentra es NULL en todo el momento.

Comment: si tu haces un find by id y te sale null no esta en la bd. depura mira lo que devuelve el servicio si el servicio devuelve null la id no es correcta o esta mirano otra bd